# Why is Astro site not building with Contentful fields?

Tags: typescript, contentful, astrojs

I have an Astro site that uses Contentful as a CMS.

I want to fetch data from Contentful to display on the website. I've been following the [guidance on the Astro site](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/cms/contentful/).

**lib/contentful.ts**

```
import contentful, { type EntryFieldTypes, type Asset } from "contentful";

export interface homepage {
  contentTypeId: "page",
  fields: {
    introductionTitle: EntryFieldTypes.Text
    introductionSubtitle: EntryFieldTypes.Text
    heroImage: Asset
  }
}
```

Then display the results on **index.astro**

```
import { contentfulClient } from "../lib/contentful";
import type { homepage } from "../lib/contentful";

const entries = await contentfulClient.getEntries<homepage>({
  content_type: "page",
});

const pages = entries.items.map((item) => {
  const { introductionTitle, introductionSubtitle, heroImage } = item.fields;
  return {
    introductionTitle,
    introductionSubtitle,
    heroImage
  };
});
```

This works great on the development server, however when I go to build the site locally or deploy the site to Vercel I get the following error:

> ▶ src/pages/index.astro
> └─ /index.htmlCannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fields')

Comment: Maybe do a `console.log(entries.items[0])` to see what the JSON returned looks like?

Comment: All looks as expected, it’s only when I try to build it that I encounter the issue.

Comment: I mean put console.log in and then do a build.

Comment: It still returns everything as usual in the console.

Comment: well, the error is saying that `item.fields` is undefined at some point... so maybe log the whole `items` array then?